# Сортировка и фильтр поля из связанной модели Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

И снова про фильтр и сортировку связанных моделей в Yii2 если позволите... сделал все по инструкции но не работает, если не затруднит ткните носом где неправда.
Есть 2 модели User и Order, у одного User может быть несколько Order, у Order соответственно только 1 User, связаны через user.id = order.user_id что описано в связях yii:

**User.php**

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

**Order.php**

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Есть класс **OrderSearch.php**, в котором добавлено поле, которое мне надо получить из таблица user - **email**, туда соответственно добавлена переменная

```
public $email;
...

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            .....
            [['email'], 'safe']
        ];
    }
```

Сортировку и фильтр хочу производить по id заказа, date и как раз полю email.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'date',
            'email' => [
                'asc' => ['user.email' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['user.email' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => 'Email'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Жадная загрузка данных модели

```
if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            $query->joinWith(['user']);
            return $dataProvider;
        }
```

Далее

```
$query->andFilterWhere......
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.email', $this->email]);

        return $dataProvider;
```

В **OrderController.php**

```
...
        $searchModel = new OrderSearch();
        $dataProvider = searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
...
```

И сама вьюшка **index.php**

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',
            'date',
            'summ',
            'delivery_summ',
            'delivery_rus',
            'email',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
...
```

В таком случае ошибка **Getting unknown property: app\models\Order::email**

Если ставим вместо 'email' - 'user.email' то все отображается, но нет фильтра и сортировки на этом поле (на id и date есть)

Comment: Вы жадную загрузку явно не там делаете. Сделайте join перед условием.

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка по связанным данным

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'category' => SORT_ASC,
        ],
    ],
]);
$query->joinWith(['category category']);
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['category'] = [
    'asc' => ['category.name' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['category.name' => SORT_DESC],
];
```